# Cómo evito se realice la petición hasta que realmente la máscara de fecha se haya completado?

Tags: jquery, ajax, momentjs

Tengo el siguiente código aplicado a un `input` de tipo text al que se le aplica una máscara de tipo fecha con formato **dd/mm/yyyy**:

```
/**
 * Aplicar la máscara de fecha a todos los elementos con clase ´mask-date´
**/
$('.mask-date').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', {'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'});

$('#embarazada_fechaUltimaMenstruacion').on('keyup', function (e) {
            moment.locale('es');
            var f = $(this).val();
            console.log(f);
            var fum = moment(f, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
            if (fum.isValid()) {
                $.get(Routing.generate('embarazadas_calcular_posibleEG', {'f': fum.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}), function (r) {
                    console.log(r);
                    $('#infoEG').html(r);
                });
            }
        });
```

La cuestión es que `moment.js` me toma como válida todas las fechas a medida que se completa el formato de la máscara aplicada, porque internamente el objeto fecha creado por moment.js se va completando con los componentes de fecha del día actual, y por tanto siempre es válido el valor evaluado dentro de la función y la petición `$.get` se realiza tantas veces hasta que se complete la fecha, lo que hace poco óptimo el código.
Cómo evito se realice la petición hasta que realmente la máscara de fecha se haya completado??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el evento `keyup` por uno que indique mejor que el usuario ya terminó. Digamos, cuando el campo pierda el foco. Eso sería `blur`.

```
$('#embarazada_fechaUltimaMenstruacion').on('blur', function (e) {
            moment.locale('es');
            var f = $(this).val();
            console.log(f);
            var fum = moment(f, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
            if (fum.isValid()) {
                $.get(Routing.generate('embarazadas_calcular_posibleEG', {'f': fum.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}), function (r) {
                    console.log(r);
                    $('#infoEG').html(r);
                });
            }
        });
```

La otra opción es usar la función `focusout` que es equivalente

```
$('#embarazada_fechaUltimaMenstruacion').focusout(function (e) {
            moment.locale('es');
            var f = $(this).val();
            console.log(f);
            var fum = moment(f, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
            if (fum.isValid()) {
                $.get(Routing.generate('embarazadas_calcular_posibleEG', {'f': fum.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}), function (r) {
                    console.log(r);
                    $('#infoEG').html(r);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! Me sirvió focusout.

Comment: @Francisco súper! recuerda entonces marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros sabrán cuál es la solución a este problema